# Is there any way to give user input one by one to a running .exe file in php

Tags: php

I want to run .exe file from php. It asks for user input one by one. Is there any way I can do this.
I tried using shell_exec(), exec() but they didn't return the expected results.

Comment: Hello, please show your code. Without code, we can't help you because we don't know what your logic looks like in this case.

Comment: Hi, I just used shell_exec() function to run .exe file but now I am unable find a way to pass user input to it.
$output=shell_exec("file.exe");

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my own query, please find the piece of code below that solved the purpose:

```
$descriptorspec = array(
0 => array("pipe", "r"),
1 => array("pipe", "w"),
2 => array("file", "error.txt", "a")
);

$process = proc_open('xyz.exe', $descriptorspec, $pipes);
$input1 = "1";
if (is_resource($process)) {
print fgets($pipes[1]); // this will help you read the lines
fwrite($pipes[0], $input1."\n"); // to provide input
print fgets($pipes[1]); 
fclose($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[0]);
$return_value = proc_close($process);

echo "command returned $return_value\n";

} else {
echo "Resource unavailable";
}
```